# Connect to slicehost from MediaTemple with a PHP Script (GS Hosting)

Tags: php, sockets, networking, mediatemple, slicehost

I want use a Redis server with a PHP Site hosted on a MediaTemple GS hosting.

MT allows PHP Sockets to contact an external server (slicehost)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MediaTemple just respond to me.

> Yes, you can. There is nothing
>   preventing you from opening outgoing
>   socket connections.